# Limit Linux Debian user privilleges

Tags: linux, user, debian, privileges

Hi I need to create user on Linux Debian that can only access /usr/src/xxx catalog and use screen command to run server. Could you help me with it? I would be really thankful. Have a nice day!

Comment: Google `chroot` (et al.)

Comment: Also the restricted shell options in `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, etc...